# Google Maps Marker Click Event Bubbling

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a marker on a Google Map using the v3 Javascript API that is beneath another marker.  When I click on the topmost marker, I would like to have the click event bubble up (down?) to the bottom-most marker with the goal of providing an optional menu for the user to choose which marker they meant to click.

Is this possible with the google.maps.event.addListener for click events?

Can I query the map for all markers that are contained by a given location, apart from hacking it myself?

Comment: Do you store your markers coords in a db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a builtin way to cycle through the markers on the click event. You can control the zIndex of each marker via the [MarkerOptions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerOptions) which will override the default stacking based on vertical position:

> All markers are displayed on the map
>   in order of their zIndex, with higher
>   values displaying in front of markers
>   with lower values. By default, markers
>   are displayed according to their
>   vertical position on screen, with
>   lower markers appearing in front of
>   markers further up the screen.

It think you will have to code this up yourself. I would love to hear how that goes.

Comment: You're right, there isn't a built-in way.  I just cycle through my own markers.  I don't have a ton so it's fast for now.